# Iterate images and convert to base64 format for table OCR in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, base64

I have several image format tables from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ho3visres55kpoy/test.zip?dl=0) and I'm able to extract them one by one use the following code.

```
import base64
from tencentcloud.common import credential
from tencentcloud.common.profile.client_profile import ClientProfile
from tencentcloud.common.profile.http_profile import HttpProfile
from tencentcloud.common.exception.tencent_cloud_sdk_exception import TencentCloudSDKException 
from tencentcloud.ocr.v20181119 import ocr_client, models 

path = './test/1.png'
def imgget(path):
    with open(path,'rb') as f: 
        base64_data = base64.b64encode(f.read())
    return base64_data.decode('utf-8')

try: 
    cred = credential.Credential('***', '***') 
    httpProfile = HttpProfile()
    httpProfile.endpoint = 'ocr.tencentcloudapi.com'
 
    clientProfile = ClientProfile()
    clientProfile.httpProfile = httpProfile
    client = ocr_client.OcrClient(cred, 'ap-guangzhou', clientProfile) 
 
    req = models.TableOCRRequest()
    
    params = imgget(path)
    req.ImageBase64 = str(params)
    # req.from_json_string(params)
 
    resp = client.TableOCR(req)
    # print(resp.to_json_string())
 
except TencentCloudSDKException as err: 
    print(err)
    
data = base64.b64decode(resp.Data)

def save(data, name):
    path = name
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)
    f.close
# print(data)
name = './data/1.xlsx'
save(data, name)
```

But now I want iterate all the image files from the link in the beginging of this question and pass them to `path = './test/1.png'`, then extract tables and save them in one sheet of one excel file in Python, how could I modify the code above to do that?

Thank you.

**Update:**

We can loop all the images's path with:

```
for path in glob.iglob('./test/*.png'):
    print(path)
```

Out:

```
./test/4.png
./test/3.png
./test/2.png
./test/1.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution so far, not able to save result into one excel file but it works somehow.

Welcome to improve it.

```
import base64
from tencentcloud.common import credential
from tencentcloud.common.profile.client_profile import ClientProfile
from tencentcloud.common.profile.http_profile import HttpProfile
from tencentcloud.common.exception.tencent_cloud_sdk_exception import TencentCloudSDKException 
from tencentcloud.ocr.v20181119 import ocr_client, models 
import glob
import os

directory = './images/test/'

def imgget(path):
    with open(path,'rb') as f: 
        base64_data = base64.b64encode(f.read())
    return base64_data.decode('utf-8')

# save files
def save(data, name):
    path = name
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)
    f.close
                
try: 
    cred = credential.Credential('***', '***') 
    httpProfile = HttpProfile()
    httpProfile.endpoint = 'ocr.tencentcloudapi.com'
 
    clientProfile = ClientProfile()
    clientProfile.httpProfile = httpProfile
    client = ocr_client.OcrClient(cred, 'ap-guangzhou', clientProfile) 
 
    req = models.TableOCRRequest()
    
    for image in os.listdir(directory):        
        if image.endswith(".png") or image.endswith(".jpg"):
            print(image)
            file_names = os.path.splitext(image)[0]
            print(file_names)
            path = os.path.join(directory, image)
            params = imgget(path)
            req.ImageBase64 = str(params)
            # req.from_json_string(params)
            resp = client.TableOCR(req)

            data = base64.b64decode(resp.Data)
            print(data)
            name = './tables/{}.xlsx'.format(file_names)
            save(data, name)
            continue
        else:
            pass
 
except TencentCloudSDKException as err:
    print(err)
```